# Windows 10 on SSD never boot

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, ssd, bios

I bought a new Kingstom SSD 240GB with Windows 10 already installed. I tested it on a newer hardware setup and it works fine, but when i tried to install in a old hardware, it won't work.

The **SSD is recognized by the bios, but the OS is never booted**. It keeps showing the message "*reboot and select proper boot device*"

- I tried to change the SATA Mode from IDE to AHCI.
- I tried to change the boot priority from SSD Hard Drive to UEFI.

The motherboard is **MSI H61M-P21 (B3)** and it was working fine with an older HD.

Comment: Just to confirm the drive is formatted as GPT and CSM is disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new disk is most likely formatted as GPT with Windows 10 64-bit,
but your old disk was probably MBR and you were booting in Legacy mode.
According to
[MSI documentation](https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/H61MP21_B3)
your motherboard supports UEFI.

I suggest:

- Boot with the old disk to install the latest
  [BIOS Version 19.2](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/H61MP21_B3#down-bios)
  from 2013-01-09 (unless already installed)
- Replace the disk with the new one
- Boot into the BIOS/UEFI and ensure that Legacy mode is Off.
  It may also be called Compatibility Support Module (CSM).
- Close and save the BIOS
- The new disk should now boot.

In case of a problem, verify the format of the new disk and the
installed Windows version from the vendor.